# Group by and sum based on column values without sum() over()?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We have a table [Kpis] that looks like the following:

```
RawId   EmpId     Date         Hour  Min   KpiValue   KpiName
106     ABC123    20160310     8     0     3           Kpi1
124     ABC123    20160310     8     0     65          Kpi1
121     ABC123    20160310     8     15    12          Kpi2
109     ABC109    20160310     8     0     34          Kpi2
112     ABC908    20160310     9     5     3           Kpi1
118     ABC907    20160310     8     30    24          Kpi1
115     ABC123    20160310     8     15    54          Kpi1
```

I would like to group by EmpId, KpiName, Date, Hour. So, for example, with this data, **Kpi1** for EmpId **ABC123** at Hour **8** would be **122**.

So I tried using the CASE statement, but the result is incorrect. I haven't checked the actual totals in the result, but the sums should be correct. It's the format of the result that's incorrect; every empid has two rows: one for Kpi1 and one for Kpi2.

```
select empid, 
case kpiname when 'Kpi1' then sum(kpivalue) end as 'Kpi1',
case kpiname when 'Kpi2' then sum(kpivalue) end as 'Kpi2'
from 
[Kpis]
where kpiname in ('Kpi1', 'Kpi2')
and date = 20160310 and hour = 8
group by empid, kpiname, hour
```

How can I use the Case statement to fix the results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the case inside your sum, such that you for each KpiName only sums the relevant values.

```
SELECT
    EmpId,
    [Hour], 
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN KpiName = 'Kpi1' THEN KpiValue
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) Kpi1,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN KpiName = 'Kpi2' THEN KpiValue
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) Kpi2
FROM
    Kpis
GROUP BY
    EmpId,
    [Hour]
```

This produces this output

```
EmpId   Hour    Kpi1    Kpi2
ABC109  8       0       34
ABC123  8       122     12
ABC907  8       24      0
ABC908  9       3       0
```

Answer (score 0):

SUM fucntion have to be outside of CASE:

```
select empid, 
    sum(case kpiname when 'Kpi1' then kpivalue end) as 'Kpi1',
    sum(case kpiname when 'Kpi2' then kpivalue end) as 'Kpi2'
from 
    [Kpis]
where kpiname in ('Kpi1', 'Kpi2')
and date = 20160310 and hour = 8
group by empid, kpiname, hour
```

Comment: you should add "ELSE 0" to your cases, otherwise the case will return NULL

Comment: @FLICKER CASE returns NULL when not exist values that match the condition, in this particular case Kpi1 and Kpi2 exist.

Comment: you are right, but generally it is a good practice to have that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the PIVOT functionality, which I believe is what you're actually trying to accomplish.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        EmpId,
        KpiName,
        [Hour],
        KpiValue
    FROM
        Kpis
) SourceTable

PIVOT (
    SUM(KpiValue)
    FOR KpiName
    IN ([Kpi1],[Kpi2])
) PivotTable
```

Which gives this output. Note the NULLs as opposed to the zeros, correctly showing the lack of data.

```
EmpId   Hour    Kpi1    Kpi2
ABC109  8       NULL    34
ABC123  8       122     12
ABC907  8       24      NULL
ABC908  9       3       NULL
```